# Stop Chrome Auto Updates Mac!!! For Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chromium, auto-update

I have been trying to learn selenium, but my chrome auto-updates every hour its so annoying. It will stay at 114 for a while after I install the right version off one of these websites:

https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/versions
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

but then it just goes back. I don't know how or why.

I've tried everything from deleting the SoftwareUpdate folder, doing the chmod thing to stop permissions, I dont know what to do anymore. I heard that you can download something called chromium and keep it from auto-updating but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be so greatly appreciated.